# Odometer program. please suggest me some suggestions regarding this error

Tags: c++

My requirement:

> Define a class called Odometer that will be used to track fuel and mileage for an automotive vehicle.  The class should have member variables to track the miles driven and the fuel efficiency of the vehicle in miles per gallon.  Include a mutator function to reset the odometer to zero miles, a mutator function to set the fuel efficiency, a mutator function that accepts miles driven for a trip and adds it to the odometer’s total, and an accessor method that returns the number of gallons of gasoline that the vehicle has consumed since the odometer was last reset.
>
> Use your class with a test program that creates several trips with different fuel efficiencies.

```
  #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class Odometer

  {
 public:

Odometer();

void reset();
void totalfuel();

void input_miles(int getmiles);
void Odometer::set_fuel_efficiency(double fuel_efficiency);

double Odometer::getgallons();
int gallonsUsed;

  private:
int milesDriven;
double fuel_efficiency;
int getmiles;   
};

Odometer::Odometer()
{   
milesDriven = 0;
fuel_efficiency = 0;    
}

void Odometer::reset()
 {
milesDriven = 0;
}

void Odometer::totalfuel()
{
fuel_efficiency = (milesDriven/gallonsUsed);
}

void Odometer::input_miles(int miles_driven)
{
milesDriven = milesDriven + miles_driven;

}

 void Odometer::set_fuel_efficiency(double Fuel_efficiency)
 {
fuel_efficiency = Fuel_efficiency;
 }

 double Odometer::getgallons()
 {
return milesDriven/fuel_efficiency;
 } 


 int main()
 {

  Odometer CarOdometer;
  int number_of_miles_driven;
   double fuel_efficiency;

  cout << "Please enter the amount of miles driven : " << endl;
   cin >> number_of_miles_driven;

CarOdometer.input_miles(number_of_miles_driven);


cout << "Enter Fuel Amount: " << endl;
cin >> fuel_efficiency;

 return 0;
  }
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:16:7: error: extra qualification â��Odometer::â�� on member â��set_fuel_efficiencyâ�� [-fpermissive]
  void Odometer::set_fuel_efficiency(double fuel_efficiency);
       ^
main.cpp:18:9: error: extra qualification â��Odometer::â�� on member â��getgallonsâ�� [-fpermissive]
  double Odometer::getgallons();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change

```
void Odometer::set_fuel_efficiency(double fuel_efficiency);

double Odometer::getgallons();
```

to

```
void set_fuel_efficiency(double fuel_efficiency);

double getgallons();
```

Comment: as per my requirement is my program is perfectly alright or any changes or any code should be added?

Comment: I guess you can check that by yourself ;)

Comment: code is running perfectly without errors.... am giving inputs and compiling through online compiler.. but it is not taking input values

Answer (score 0):

Your member function declarations have qualification of the enclosing class. This is not valid according to the C++ standard:

```
class Odometer {
    void Odometer::member();
};
```

Simply remove the superfluous qualifications from the member declarations:

```
class Odometer {
    void member();
};
```

Comment: thank you...how to strip that friend?

Comment: code is running perfectly without errors.... am giving inputs and compiling through online compiler.. but it is not taking input values

Comment: @Parveen If you have a new question, create a new question.

Comment: till 60 minutes no new question can be posted by me... :(